# Gensim FastText compute Training Loss

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim, fasttext

I am training a `fastText` model using [`gensim.models.fasttext`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html). However, I can't seem to find a method to compute the loss of the iteration for logging purposes. If I look at [`gensim.models.word2vec`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), it has the `get_latest_training_loss` method which allows you to print the training loss. Are there any alternatives or it is simply impossible?

Comment: did you find the solution for the problem..?

Comment: @gaurav1207 in the end, I just trained the model using API provided by Facebook https://fasttext.cc/

Comment: Seems like gensim 4.0.0 is going to add the `get_latest_training_loss` [method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.get_latest_training_loss)

Comment: You could follow this link. I think they will update soon. https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2617

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gensim word2vec print log loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888490/gensim-word2vec-print-log-loss)