# gensim word2vec print log loss

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

how to print to log (file or stout) the loss of each epoch in the training phase, when using gensim word2vec model.

I tried :

```
 logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
 logging.root.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
```

But I didn't saw any loss printing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the latest training loss of a word2vec model with the method `get_latest_training_loss()`. If you want to print the loss after every epoch you can add a callback that does this. For example:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

class callback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    '''Callback to print loss after each epoch.'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.epoch = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()
        print('Loss after epoch {}: {}'.format(self.epoch, loss))
        self.epoch += 1

model = Word2Vec(common_texts, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, 
                 compute_loss=True, callbacks=[callback()])
```

However, the loss is computed in a cumulative way (i.e. the loss that gets printed after each epoch is the total loss of all epochs so far). See [gojomo's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067942/10921263) for more explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This can print loss for each epoch. Thanks @Anna Krogager

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.word2vec import LineSentence
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

class callback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    '''Callback to print loss after each epoch.'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.epoch = 0
        self.loss_to_be_subed = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()
        loss_now = loss - self.loss_to_be_subed
        self.loss_to_be_subed = loss
        print('Loss after epoch {}: {}'.format(self.epoch, loss_now))
        self.epoch += 1

model = Word2Vec(LineSentence('./data/house_list'), size=100, workers=20, \
                    min_count=1, iter=30, window=5, compute_loss=True, callbacks=[callback()])
model.save('./model/v2.model')
```

Comment: how is that an improvement over Anna Krogager's?

Comment: fixes the cumulative loss problem i think